# How do i acheive nice edge flow around this mesh

Tags: topology

I want to create a nice supporting loop around the edge of this mesh. With nice edge flow.

But I keep coming to the same outcome which doesn't flow properly

[image]

Comment: Do you want just a nice edge loop along the non-manifold edges or support loops to control the curvature of the faces that the Subdivision Surface* modifier creates?

Answer (score 0):

Two things;

1. Make sure that your madifiers are in the right order.
    First the Mirror Modifier and then the Subdivision Surface Modifier.
2. Make sure that `Merge` is turned on in the mirror modifier and the value of merge distance is something small. (It's 0.001m by default)

[image]

Now if the merge doesn't do its thing then try this: Turn on clipping in the Mirror Modifier. Go to edit mode. And just move the vertices near the mirroring boundary by just the enough amount to snap them to the boundary.